# A Query regarding the value of Exit Status of Child Process Created with fork()

Tags: c, fork, waitpid

Just have a query about Status of Child processes created with fork()

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main (){
    int pid;
    int status;

    printf("Parent: %d\n", getpid());

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0){
        printf("Child %d\n", getpid());
        sleep(4);
        exit(1);
       }

  waitpid(pid, &status, 0);

  printf("The status of child is %u\n",status);


  printf("Parent: %d\n", getpid());

  return 0;
  }
```

I expect the status to print 1 , but it prints 256(a byte of 0's is added )

Can someone explain why is this? I am a newbie to C , so please excuse as this question may appear silly to the experts.

Comment: Either use `WEXITSTATUS(status)` or do `status >> 8`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does wait() set status to 256 instead of the -1 exit status of the forked process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659616/why-does-wait-set-status-to-256-instead-of-the-1-exit-status-of-the-forked-pr)

Comment: Another duplicate [I used wait(&status) and the value of status is 256, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130990/i-used-waitstatus-and-the-value-of-status-is-256-why)

Answer (score 2):

From [man waitpid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html):

> If wstatus is not NULL, wait() and waitpid() store status information
>          in the int to which it points.  This integer can be inspected with
>          the following macros (which take the integer itself as an argument,
>          not a pointer to it, as is done in wait() and waitpid()!):
>
> WEXITSTATUS(stat_val)
>
> If the value of WIFEXITED(stat_val) is non-zero, this macro evaluates to the low-order 8 bits of the status argument that the child process passed to _exit() or exit(), or the value the child process returned from main().

So you should:

```
printf("The status of child is %u\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
```