# call shell run pipeline failed in rust's Command.output

Tags: rust

I'm trying to get result from call shell and grep the result.  But it failed, in shell, it works.

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let result = Command::new("sh")
        .arg("-c")
        .arg("last")                // by this line it works
        // .arg("last | grep 'still logged in'")  // by this line, it will return 256 code
        .output()
        .expect("'last' command failed to start");
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Fedora 31. What OS? And can you run `sh -c "last | grep 'still logged in'"` from a terminal yourself successfully?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo [This is reproducible even on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=dfc7b9aa9f302a13e0f6da3557fecb65). Running directly from the terminal and inspecting `$?` will print 1, but the Rust code prints 256.

Comment: I can successful running "last | grep xx" on linux.  it's return the result. but through rust's process, seems pipe line command can not work.  maybe can change to other simple shell command also reproduce this.

Answer (score 2):

https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.ExitStatus.html

> An `ExitStatus` represents every possible disposition of a process. On Unix this is the **wait status**. It is *not* simply an *exit status* (a value passed to `exit`).

See [I used wait(&status) and the value of status is 256, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130990/i-used-waitstatus-and-the-value-of-status-is-256-why). `grep` returns `1` as no match was found, and this becomes an exist status of `256`.

If you want the exit code, call [`output.status.code()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.ExitStatus.html#method.code). [This correctly returns `Some(1)`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c7beac4cde601365abde98950cce587e).